# jQuery - Looping through div children and appending to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning qQuery and am trying to write a for loop that loops through the child elements of a div element and appends each child element to another div.
My code is below:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < $('.div_select_char').children().length; i++) {
  console.log($('.div_select_char').children().eq(i));
  $('.div_select_enemy').append($('.div_select_char').children().eq(i));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The problem I'm having is that only 2 child elements (of 4 total) are appended to the new div, not all of them. I can't figure this out. Your help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Check the value of `i` and the number of children on each iteration of the loop and you should find the problem.

Comment: Or you can simply remove the loop completely, as it is not necessary for this task -> `$('.div_select_enemy').append($('.div_select_char').children())`

Answer (score -1):

Rather than invoking the function over and over again on every single loop, you'd better store the value of the functions to a variable. It's leverage your script performance, and of course, also make your logic inside loop to rely on precise length to loop for.

What I mean is, the `append` method will move the element to the desired container. So when you loop into it, below `length` would give different result

```
// start loop
$('.div_select_char').children().length // then append, length = 4
$('.div_select_char').children().length // then append, length = 3
$('.div_select_char').children().length // then append, length = 2
$('.div_select_char').children().length // then append, length = 1
// end loop
```

The `length` is continuously decremented on each loop. Then, it would be better to store the start amount to loop as follow

```
var len = $('.div_select_char').children().length;

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  console.log($('.div_select_char').children().eq(i));
  $('.div_select_enemy').append($('.div_select_char').children().eq(i));
}
```

The problem will still occuring since whenever you call `$('.div_select_char').children()` inside the loop, its result will give different value since you're `append`ing it. So, store its first result just like you store the `length` as above

```
var len = $('.div_select_char').children().length;
var $children = $('.div_select_char').children();
var $enemyContainer = $('.div_select_enemy');

for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  console.log($children.eq(i));
  $enemyContainer.append($children.eq(i));
}
```

Since `.children()` returns a collection that jQuery can also chain a loop `.each()` method, you can actually make codes much simpler

```
var $enemyContainer = $('.div_select_enemy');

$('.div_select_char').children().each(function () {
   $enemyContainer.append($(this))
})
```

Working example

```js
var $dest = $('#dest')

$('#origin').children().each(function (){
  $dest.append($(this))
})
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.parent {
  width: 50%;
  height: 12rem;
  position: relative;
}

.parent > .child {
  height: 3rem;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent:before {
  opacity: .7;
  font-size: small;
  position: absolute;
}

#origin {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}

#origin:before {
  content: 'origin';
}

#dest {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#dest:before {
  content: 'destination';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="origin" class="parent">
 <div class="child">1</div>
 <div class="child">2</div>
 <div class="child">3</div>
 <div class="child">4</div>
</div>

<div id="dest" class="parent">

</div>
```

Comment: i mean... you don't even need the .each.

Comment: @KevinB You're right, but I stand mine, the OP is asking about loop. Not kinda howtos...

Comment: The reason I'm asking for a loop format is because I would like to compare the properties of each child element to each other.